# How to save a copy of image after using variant option in ActiveStorage.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I am facing this issue with ActiveStorage where I need to process an image, my requirement is to save the processed image and attach it to a new model after crop and other transformations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@George has a great answer, still I would mention mine,which should work with rails 5.2 as per my understanding of your question,

Create a temporary file, and fetch the file first, if it is in your cloud storage, if not then you don't need this part, just get the path using blob in that case.

```
path = Rails.root.join('tmp', ModelVariable.main_image.blob.filename.to_s).to_s
File.open(path, 'wb') do |file|
  file.write(ModelVariable.main_image.blob.download)
end
```

Do your customization

```
customize_image = MiniMagick::Image.open(path)
customize_image.crop(crop_params)
```

Attach it to the different model you wanted to

```
file = File.open(customize_image.path)
filename = Time.zone.now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S") + ModelVariable.main_image.blob.filename.to_s
NewModelVaribale.customized_image.attach(io: file, filename: filename)
```

Save it

```
customized_product.save
```

Hope this works for you :)

Comment: Hello Faizaan! I used a customized version of your code that helps me a lot. I can replace the original file attached with the cropped version instead of having a second file attached for the cropped version. My question is: is-it possible to manage all the crop without a temp file (in the tmp folder), so in memory I suppose ?

Answer (score 5):

`ActiveStorage::Blob#variant` accommodates a different use case, so deal with [`ActiveStorage::Variation`](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Variation.html) directly. The following assumes latest Rails master rather than Rails 5.2:

```
variation = ActiveStorage::Variation.new(resize_to_fit: [100, 100], crop: true)

message.header_image.open do |input|
  variation.transform(input, format: "png") do |output|
    message.cropped_header_image.attach \
      io: output,
      filename: "#{message.header_image.filename.base}.png",
      content_type: "image/png"
  end
end
```

Comment: How can I crop using x-coord  y-coord as starting point and width and height from there? Or using x1,y1 and x2,y2

Comment: @George Claghorn can you please provide references to the methods you are calling? I don't remember any `open` method on attachments, and calling that method throws a private method error

Comment: @SampsonCrowley: It’s in Rails master and will be released in Rails 6. https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Blob.html#method-i-open

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add this to Faizaan's answer

If you are storing locally use

```
path = ActiveStorage::Blob.service.send(:path_for, ModelVariable.main_image.blob.key)
```

Comment: As version `6.0.3.4`, path_for is a public instance method, so can be invoked directly instead using `send`.